# How to get rid of text box artifact with Fivestar module?

Tags: rating, entities

I'm using Drupal 7.14 and Fivestar 7.x-2.0-alpha2.  There is a text box artifact displayed below the stars on all nodes with a Fivestar field (see screenshot below).
[image: text box artifact]

Here is the HTML/CSS source for this screenshot:

```
  <span rel="sioc:reply_of" resource="/node/1" class="rdf-meta"></span><div class="field field-name-comment-body field-type-text-long field-label-hidden"><div class="field-items"><div class="field-item even" property="content:encoded"><p>great</p>
</div></div></div><div class="field field-name-field-reader-rating field-type-fivestar field-label-above"><div class="field-label">Reader Rating:&nbsp;</div><div class="field-items"><div class="field-item even"><div class="clearfix fivestar-user-stars"><div class="fivestar-static-form-item"><div class="form-item form-type-item">
 <div class="fivestar-default"><div class="fivestar-widget-static fivestar-widget-static-vote fivestar-widget-static-5 clearfix"><div class="star star-1 star-odd star-first"><span class="on">3</span></div><div class="star star-2 star-even"><span class="on"></span></div><div class="star star-3 star-odd"><span class="on"></span></div><div class="star star-4 star-even"><span class="off"></span></div><div class="star star-5 star-odd star-last"><span class="off"></span></div></div></div>
<div class="description"><div class="fivestar-summary fivestar-summary-"></div></div>
</div>
```

I suspect that `<div class="fivestar-summary fivestar-summary-"></div>` is what is creating this empty text box.

This empty box being shown is despite having chosen `No text` in the `Text to display under the stars` dropdown menu for the Fiverstar field at `/admin/structure/types/manage/$content_type/display` (where `$content_stype` is a dummy for whatever content type I am editing).
[image: fivestar settings]

Am I missing something?

- Is there another option somewhere to get rid of this annoying text-box?
- Is this the default behavior of Fivestar/would I need to manually modify Fivestar to fix this?
- Or is this a bug that noone has reported yet (I couldn't find anything that sounded like this issue [here](http://drupal.org/project/issues/search/fivestar))?  I would think that if this was a bug someone would have reported it already (it is pretty noticable) so I'm inclined to think I am just missing something--but if people think that this is a bug, please indicate as much and I will remove the question and file an issue!

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: @whitefleaCH Thanks for your response.  Adding `div.description { display: none; }` with CSS injector gets rid of it.  But I feel that there should be a better way that I'm missing (I'm following the "Using Drupal" book and their screenshot doesn't have these boxes or mention a CSS workaround).  Also I'm a little wary that down the road this could affect some other element also called `description`.  Nonetheless, if you add your comment as an answer and I don't hear any better ideas in a few days I'll accept your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Can't you get rid of it with CSS? `display: none;`